# mpack description (-d) from a script variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

In my script I have a variable named *$message*. I want to send this message together with a jpeg using `mpack`.

One way that works:

```
echo "$message" > myText
mpack -s "test mail" -d myText myImage.jpg john@example.com
```

However, I would like to dispense with writing the file *myText* and directly pass the contents of *$message* to the `-d` parameter.

How can this be done?

BTW: My `$message` variable contains two sub-strings separated by a linefeed.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. A named pipe did the trick:

```
mkfifo fifo
echo "$message" > fifo &
mpack -s "test mail" -d fifo myImage.jpg john@example.com
rm fifo
```